# Loopy newcommand causes hanged processing

Tags: macros

By a too quick search/replace of "mathcal" by "mc" I ended up with a loopy or recursive statement like

```
\newcommand{\mc}{\mc}
```

It seems to cause the compilation of my document to hang. Is this a known bug? (Why has it not been fixed?)

Comment: I guess it could be considered a bug, but you are trying to define something in terms of itself.  If you want to change the defintion of `\mc` use `\let\OldMc\mc` and then `\newcommand{mc}{\OldMc}`, and make any changes as required.

Comment: It's not a bug. TeX just dutifully follows its rules; you're asking that `\mc` is substituted with `\mc` which then is substituted by `\mc`… No error, no memory filling, no hanging process: just an everlasting run.

Comment: Sure, but ideally there should be some check against this sort of thing

Comment: It's the halting problem. There is no check possible in general. But any programming language allows you to write a non terminating loop: C java javascript python....

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen How can there be such a check? TeX is a language based on macro expansion, so macros are expanded. If they're badly written, infinite looping is possible. Note that it's normal in TeX programming to define a macro in terms of itself, with the provision that something happens (a conditional check of some sort) between calls, so infinite looping is prevented.

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen I totally agree with @egreg and @DavidCarlisle. What you are experiencing is actually the expected behaviour. If you don't want an infinite loop you could do `\newcommand{\mc}{\noexpand\mc}` which will clearly have other deficiencies.

Comment: @HenriMenke It would just `\relax`. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to define a macro in terms of itself.  As mentioned in the comments, you need to be careful.  The problem with `\newcommand\mc{\mc}` does not occur when it's defined but when you first try to use it, at which point, if left as is, it will recursively call itself.  Sometimes this is the behavior you want.

But sometimes you want something else, in which case you can use one of the powerful `\edef` and `\xdef` to create what you want.

Here's a completely trivial example which illustrates building a tabular environment from a list of elements.  The content of the tabular environment is built up from what was previously defined:  in other words `\ae@tabular@content` is defined in terms of itself, but precautions are taken not to expand too much (hence the use of tools from `etoolbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\makeatletter
\def\ae@tabular@content{}
\def\ae@empty@content{}
\def\aebuildtabular#1{%%
  \def\ae@tabular@content{}%%
  \foreach \myx/\myy in {#1}  
  {\ifx\ae@tabular@content\ae@empty@content
    \xdef\ae@tabular@content{\expandonce\myx & \myy }%%
   \else
    \xdef\ae@tabular@content{\expandonce\ae@tabular@content \noexpand\\ \expandonce\myx & \myy }%%
  \fi}
  \begin{tabular}{lr}
    \ae@tabular@content
  \end{tabular}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\aebuildtabular{A/Apple,B/Banana,C/Carrot,D/Daikon,E/Endive,F/Fig}

\end{document}
```

to produce

[image]

Sometimes you may want to make a recursive call to *trim* (or do something else).  This next example takes in a string and throws away tokens until it comes to the first occurence of `E` in the string.  If there is no `E`, then it just restores the original string.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\aestriptoFirstE[1]{%%
  \def\ae@old{#1}%%
  #1 $\rightarrow$ \ae@striptoE#1\@nil
}

\def\ae@old{}
\def\ae@E@test{E}
\def\ae@empty@test{}
\def\ae@striptoE#1#2\@nil{%%
  \def\ae@continue{}%%
  \def\ae@first{#1}%%
  \def\ae@second{#2}%%
  \ifx\ae@E@test\ae@first
    #2
  \else
    \ifx\ae@empty@test\ae@second
      (unchanged) \ae@old
    \else
      \def\ae@continue{\ae@striptoE#2\@nil}%%
    \fi
  \fi
  \ae@continue
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}

\aestriptoFirstE{ABCDEFGE}

\aestriptoFirstE{WXYZ}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `&` is not expandable, so `\noexpand&` does nothing more than `&` alone. What's `\ae@newcol` for?

Comment: @egreg. Hmm. I've had problems in the past with `&`.... now I don't remember what those are.  I'll clean the code.

Answer (score 9):

The declaration `\newcommand{\mc}{\mc}` ultimately becomes, in terms of TeX primitives,

```
\long\def\mc{\mc}
```

where `\long` is irrelevant for the case in discussion.

You have to consider that TeX doesn't interpret in any way the replacement text of a macro *when it stores the definition* for it. It's a necessary feature, because when we *expand* a macro, we want that the macros in the replacement text use their *current* meaning, not what was valid at definition time, when they even need not be defined!

To make a silly example, consider the macro definition

```
\newcommand{\mybreak}{BREAK\\}
```

In LaTeX, the macro `\\` changes its meaning in several occasions; it means something at the outer level, something else when a declaration such as `\centering` or `\raggedright` is in force and has a very different meaning when inside `array`, `tabular` or `tabbing`.

This is wanted! The user has to know just that `\\` causes a line break. Then `\mybreak` can be used in any situation where `\\` can be given, because the `\\` token in the replacement text will be interpreted (expanded and executed) at call time.

Here's an example from the TeXbook:

```
\def\hex{{\count0=\n \divide\n by16
  \ifnum\n>0 \hex\fi \count2=\n \multiply\count2 by-16
  \advance\count0 by\count2 \hexdigit}}
\def\hexdigit{\ifnum\count0<10 \number\count0
  \else\advance\count0 by-10 \advance\count0 by`A \char\count0 \fi}
```

The token `\n` is supposed to be a count register. As you see, the macro `\hex` has a replacement text calling `\hex` itself; however at every call the value of `\n` will decrease, so eventually the call of `\hex`, which happens in the true branch of a conditional, will not take place and the macro's work will come to a happy ending.

Thus, a simplistic check that the replacement text of a macro doesn't contain the macro itself can't be implemented, because it would make recursion much more difficult, if not impossible.

This of course has a price: your definition causes TeX, when it finds `\mc` to replace `\mc` with `\mc`, which then it replaces with `\mc`… Bingo! Infinite loop. The program doesn't hang: it's just dutifully replacing a token with itself without using up resources in the computer; no error will be raised, because there's nothing wrong, from the point of view of the machine, which just follows the rules.

A different case would be

```
\newcommand{\mc}{(\mc)}
```

Now at the first call of `\mc` some part of TeX's memory would fill up, in this case the “input stack”, which is assigned a size of 5000 by TeX Live 2013 (simultaneous input sources): the expansion of `\mc` pushes the first `(` on the stack while expanding `\mc`, which pushes `(` on the stack while expanding `\mc`… Another infinite loop, but this one fills the memory.

Assuming `\mc` is originally defined as a parameterless macro, adding parentheses to either end of its replacement text can be accomplished by

```
\expandafter\def\expandafter\mc\expandafter{\expandafter(\mc)}
```

because the chain of `\expandafter`'s will put a finger inside the replacement text *before* the definition is performed. In this case, however, the new replacement text will not contain `\mc` (assuming it didn't in the original definition).

An equivalent construction would be

```
\edef\mc{(\unexpanded\expandafter{\mc})}
```

but this would take us too far (it need e-TeX, so it's not available with Knuth's TeX).